# Get value from enum Java

Tags: java, enums, enumeration

I have an enum defined as follows.

```
public enum AgeRange {
    YOUNG(10,15),
    ADULT(20,50);

    private final int value;

    private AgeRange (int value) {
        this.value = value
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

I want a result that is displayed as follows:

1. If I ask for young then it displays a young person between 10 and 15 years old.
2. If I ask for adult then I get an adult between 20 and 50 years old

how to ask the user to enter an integer value and not a string ( with java.util.Scanner) and return the result via a system.out.println in a main function

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your enum doesn't compile. Your constructor takes one parameter, but you're calling it with two parameters. Change it to something like this:

```
public enum AgeRange {
    YOUNG(10,15),
    ADULT(20,50);

    private final int from;
    private final int to;

    private AgeRange (int from, int to) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    public int getFrom() {
        return from;
    }
    public int getTo() {
        return from;
    }
}
```

- Now, ask your user for the age.
- Loop over AgeRange.values()
- For each range, compare the age against range.getFrom() and range.getTo()
- when you have found the correct range, return it
- Keep in mind the age may be outside the range groups you provided. What are you going to do then?

Comment: Hi @Sean Patrick Floyd, the user will enter young or adult and not the age. And I have to display the message youth is between 10 and 15 years old. can you give me an example please

Answer (score 0):

Create a constructor with two params and a method which accepts a string and displays the bounderies of a range if difined:

```
public enum AgeRange {
    YOUNG(10,15),
    ADULT(20,50);

    private final int from;
    private final int to;
    
    private AgeRange (int from,int to) {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }

    public int getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public int getTo() {
        return to;
    }
    
    public static void displayRangeBoundaries(String str) {
        for (AgeRange range : AgeRange.values()) {
            if (str.toUpperCase().equals(range.toString())) {
                System.out.println(range.toString() + " is between " + 
                        range.getFrom() + " and " + range.getTo() +
                        " years old."
                );
                return;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("No range found for: " + str);
    }
}
```

and use it like:

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a range term");
    String input = scan.nextLine(); 
    
    AgeRange.displayRangeBoundaries(input);        
}
```